# ember data custom serializer for a json

Tags: json, ember.js

I have a Session object I want to model in Ember data. (actually display sessions but it's the same)
The JSON from the server looks like this (cannot be changed):

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "page": 1, 
    "page_size": 100, 
    "total_num_objects": 7, 
    "total_num_pages": 1
  }, 
  "result": [
    {
      "api_path": "/rest/sessions/2", 
      "end_time": 1412687629.42063, 
      "hostname": "127.0.0.1", 
      "id": 2, 
      "logical_id": "c6656738-4e23-11e4-9017-685b35b63131_0", 
      "product_name": null, 
      "product_revision": null, 
      "product_version": null, 
      "start_time": 1412687629.26851, 
      "status": "SUCCESS", 
      "type": "session", 
      "user_name": null
    }, 
   {
      "api_path": "/rest/sessions/3", 
      "end_time": 1412688377.15329, 
      "hostname": "127.0.0.1", 
      "id": 3, 
      "logical_id": "84707366-4e25-11e4-a659-685b35b63131_0", 
      "product_name": null, 
      "product_revision": null, 
      "product_version": null, 
      "start_time": 1412688377.11507, 
      "status": "SUCCESS", 
      "type": "session", 
      "user_name": null
    }, 
...
```

I realize I need to write a custom `RESTSerializer` but I can't figure out what do I need to do in order go get rid of metadata + make ember realize that result is actually a session.

Side question:
Can I make the `DS.Model.extend` attributes like what I get from the API or do I  must use CamelCase and use `normalizeHash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably need to do something like this:

```
App.SessionSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
        return {
            sessions: payload.result
        };
    }
});
```

See: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizePayload

Regarding your other issue, look at `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` / `ActiveModelSerializer`.  `ActiveModelSerializer` handles the underscore convention in the JSON.